# How can i display UITableview if user hit the UITextfiled in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, uitextview

I want to display a `UITableview` if user taps a `UITextField` or a `UITextView`. Also, how can I display values in a `UITextField` or a `UITextView` if user select the multi-selection values in `UITableView`? Please give me any idea.

I am new to the programming.

Comment: Use `delegate` of `UITextField` or `UITextView`.

Comment: You can add and remove your UITableView from corresponding delegate methods. Or hide and show your UITableView

Answer (score 0):

You should use `inputView` property of `UITextfield` to show and hide `UITableView`.

Use `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method to display the values in `UITextField`

You can use `UIPickerView` and its delegate methods instead of `UITableView` to make the app more interactive.

All the best.